# JS seperate scope to incorprate multiple variables with the same name

Tags: javascript, scope

There are multiple js files and now I have to combine them into a large file.

However, since these files are familiar in function, they have many variables with the same name. So I'm wondering if there is any mechanism like namespace or scoping that can incorperate multiple variables with the same name in a file.

### Edit

And additional question:

How can I access the variabls in "ad-hoc" functions via Chrome Console?

Normally I can do this in Chrome Console:

```
[js]
var car = "Model T";

[Chrome Console]
>> car
<< "Model T"
>> car = "Model S";
>> car
<< "Model S"
```

But now, how do I get access to the variable in different scopes?

```
[js]
//lib1
(function(){
var car = "Model T";
})();
//lib2
(function(){
var car = "Model S";
})();
```

I think in @user2695276 's solution, the answer is trivial. So my question is to the ad-hoc function.

Comment: why you need to do like this? what is the reason behind this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Immediatly Invoked Function Expressions**

```
      //library 1

      (function(){

           //wrap your code within this self executing function

        var x = 'some thing';

      })();


      //library 2

      (function(){

           //wrap your code within this self executing function

        var x = 'another thing';

      })();
```

The variables will work as expected, and will not conflict.

Comment: I think this is the elegant answer since I saw these kind of things in many libraries without realizing its function.

Comment: BTW, how can I access the variables within ad-hoc function using chrome console?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking, but if it is regarding logging variables to the console, you can do it as you do normally. If you need more information from which library things are logged, you can manually append those info to the logging messages like console.log('lib 1 var x value '+x). Is this what you are looking for ?

Answer (score 2):

The variables in JS if not preceded by 'var' in their declaration are default global and sit in the global namespace. This can create naming collisions especially when multiple people write code (seems to be your case).

Namespacing:
You can have one big global variable to act as the app's topmost namespace. For example:

```
App = {
App.views = {} //encapsulates all view objects
App.views.view1 = {} // so on
}
```

This single variable first of all keeps less globals (technically one in this case). All the app's data is safely wrapped and most importantly, there is a common pattern established for developers. Everyone knows where to look for say, a 'collection' and where to make a new one.

This namespacing helps a lot in big projects. Hope you can adapt it to your scenario.

EDIT: as an afterthought, it may require architectural changes. Not sure how much time constraints you are under. But in long run, stuff like this keeps maintenance easy.

EDIT: For your additional questions, the only way to see local variables in chrome console is to bring them in scope. Look for 'breakpoint debugging in chrome dev tools'. One direct alternative is to write 'debugger' above the line you want control to pause it at runtime. From thereon you can check the runtime values of variables (hover your mouse or print in console like you normally do). Do remember to delete 'debugger' after your debugging is done :)

Comment: One of the problem of this is that I've to add "APP" to the front of every variable name.

Comment: Yes. Not exactly every variable.Do not treat it literally. At the end of the day, these are patterns. Good practices that help us. You may not keep every single global variable. But related ones. Like models, collections, views, helper functions, and so on.